# In mysql why is the cardinality of prefix index of length 1 on binary column is 534? Shouldn't it be 256?

Tags: mysql, uuid, binary-data

I created a prefix index of size 1 on a binary 16 column storing UUIds. It shown the cardinality as 532. The first character can have 256 different values then how come the cardinality is so higher than that?

```
create index my_index on my_table (foreign_key(1));

desc my_table;

Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra
foreign_key     | binary(16)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       

select count(*) from my_table;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   103979 |
+----------+



ANALYZE TABLE my_table;

show index from my_table;

+--------------------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table              | Non_unique | Key_name                                                | Seq_in_index | Column_name     | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------------------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+    
| user_problem_types |          1 | my_index                                                | 1            | my_index        | A         |         534 |        1 | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
```

Comment: Please, add your definitions

Comment: I am sorry. I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: Add your table definitions, your key definitions, explain plan (if it's some query-related issue)/show indexes output

Comment: Well binary(16) means 16-bit, 16-bit are 2bytes. And two bytes can hold higher values than 256

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the distribution of one-byte prefix keys in your index is non-uniform, and that's pushing the average number of rows per index entry out slightly.

Cardinality is calculated as roughly:

```
(Number of Rows) / (Average number of rows per index entry)
```

In your case, it looks like the sum comes out as:

```
103979 / 194
```

You and I know that you can have at most 256 distinct values in a byte, but for efficiency, cardinality is an approximation based on the calculation above. As a result, you're getting 534, which while imprecise is certainly within the correct order of magnitude and so good enough for an optimizer approximation.

Comment: This happened when I had 8000 rows as well. 534 is a consistent number.